# Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate Warning

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to apply my XML template to my site on Sharepoint, and I keep getting this warning:

```
WARNING: The source site from which the template was generated had a base template ID value of SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0,
while the current target site has a base template ID value of STS#0. This could cause potential issues while applying
the template.
```

Do you guys have any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is present because the source site from which you extracted the template is a Modern Communication site whereas the destination on which you are applying template is a classic team site.

This is a warning message not an error. If you apply the template on a Modern Communication site, this warning will not appear. It is a warning to you that there is mismatch between the source and destination site base templates.